# Unable to run 'kubectl' commands after using impersonation to fetch GKE cluster credentials

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, impersonation

## My Objective

I want to use GCP impersonation to fetch my GKE cluster credentials. And then I want to run `kubectl` commands.

## Initial Context

1. I have a GCP project called `rakib-example-project`
2. I have 2 ServiceAccounts in the project called:

   - **owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

     - it has the project-wide `roles/owner` role - so it can do anything and everything inside the GCP project
   - **executor@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

     - it only has the project-wide `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role - so it can **impersonate** the **owner** ServiceAccount in the GCP project
3. I have 1 GKE cluster in the project called `my-gke-cluster`

## The Problem

✅ I have authenticated as the **executor** ServiceAccount:

```sh
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=my_executor_sa_key.json

Activated service account credentials for: [executor@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

✅ I have fetched GKE cluster credentials by impersonating the **owner**:

```sh
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-gke-cluster \
  --zone asia-southeast1-a \
  --project rakib-example-project \
  --impersonate-service-account=owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for my-gke-cluster.
```

❌ I am failing to list cluster nodes due to missing `container.nodes.list` permission:

```sh
$ kubectl get nodes

Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "executor@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope: requires one of ["container.nodes.list"] permission(s).
```

But I have already impersonated the **Owner** ServiceAccount. Why would it still have missing permissions?

## My Limitations

It works well if i grant my **executor** ServiceAccount the `roles/container.admin` role. However, I am not allowed to grant such roles to my **executor** ServiceAccount due to compliance requirements. I can only impersonate the **owner** ServiceAccount and THEN do whatever I want through it - not directly.

Comment: By having a look to the `.kube/config` file, the impersonate feature seems missing. Can you try to run this command and retry: `gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. Let me know

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere That did it :) The `gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` did not change the contents of `~/.kube/config` in any way - it only added a `auth/impersonate_service_account` property in `gcloud config list`. And that solved it :)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you might wanna add this as the Answer to this SO question. I will accept it.

Comment: I did it. I also explain where I dug to found the workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look to your kubeconfig file at this location `~/.kube/config`, you can see the list of authorization and the secrets, such as

```
- name: gke_gdglyon-cloudrun_us-central1-c_knative
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: ya29.<secret>-9XQmaTQodj4kS39w
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2020-08-25T17:48:39Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

You see external references (`expiry-key` and `token-key`) and a `cmd-path`. The command path is interesting because when a new token need to be generated, it will be called.

However, you see any mention of the impersonation. You have to add it in the command path, to be used by default. For this, add it in your config like this:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account owner@rakib-example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Now, every use of the gcloud CLI will use the impersonate service account, and it's what you want to generate a valid access_token to reach your GKE cluster

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks :)